# Can the Wolfram Language perform conversions between organic compounds?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, chemistry

My question is straightforward - if I have a starting organic compound, say chlorobenzene and an ending organic compound, say aniline, can Wolfram give me a set of equations to go from chlorobenzene to aniline?

If this isn't currently possible, is there a way I can feed in the reactions I'm allowed to use and have it find the shortest conversion from one organic compound to another?

An extension to the question:
Is there a way to not hardcode the "types" of reactions? If the same reaction mechanism works for propane and butane, I don't want to have to individually give the reactions for both.

Comment: [`ApplyReaction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ApplyReaction.html) might be interesting to you

Comment: My former student, William Borrelli, wrote a Mathematica convenience wrapper to the IBMRxnAPI https://github.com/wrborrelli/IBMRxnAPI IBMRxn is a service that attempts to do forward and retrosynthesis prediction using machine learning based techniques.

Your problem sounds like you want to use known, established reactions. This is quite similar to the idea of Chematica, developed by Bartosz Gryzbowski and coworkers (See: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.chempr.2018.02.024 ); which is now marketed as Synthia by Sigma/Millipore/Merck